# Can't Open google.com even though there is internet

Tags: macbook-pro, internet, google

My Macbook Pro cannot able to open up "www.google.com" or "www.facebook.com".
But I can open up bing,msn and a lot other sites.  Oh And also I am not able to Open up App store from my network.

My friend's having Macbook pro too and he can reach AppStore from the same network but not me.

My Macbook Pro is 15inch Retina Display.

Why is this happening.?

I have tried fixing it in all possible ways. I browsed up a lot to sort out this issue.But in vain. I would like to ask is it me who is facing this problem or there is anybody else ? And i do need help.

There have been queries regarding this before as you can see in the below mentioned link. but no proper solution has been mentioned.

> https://discussions.apple.com/message/9276189#9276189

Comment: Which are those *all possible ways* you've tried already? Have you installed any programs which either monitors or may interfere with the network? Like Little Snitch or so?

Comment: It was brand new. And could not connect.Never installed a single a third party app. I tried providing DNS servers for google in network settings. but .. nothing changed.

Comment: Is date AND time correct on your macbook?
Does it work in another user on the same machine?

Comment: Date, Time are accurate .  They were  set up by the Apple premium dealers during the purchase.

Comment: Check your host settings in /private/etc/hosts

Comment: What host settings . What should be the default ones ? can you be a little more specific.

Comment: Open terminal and type in "sudo nano /private/etc/hosts" (without the quotes). Enter your password if prompted. Once open, verify that there is no entry like "x.x.x.x google.com" where x is a number like 198, 0, 1, etc.

Comment: It says Local host is used to configure the loopback interface.There is no mention of the word google.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I could not access Google to do an internet search. It worked fine for years, suddenly one day Google wouldn't open.
Solution: click on Finder, then click on Downloads. 
You will find a list of downloads by date, with the most recent on top.
In the past, I clicked on links containing pdf files they would download when I read them. One of those files is causing the problem. It contains some kind of virus. Find the files around the date when the problem initiated and move them to the trash. In fact, move any files that you don't recognize to the trash and then empty the trash.
Problem solved. Google will open.